# How to log or print XMLRPC XML request been sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-rpc

I am trying to debug a issue and identify why my web service call is failing. But i am unable to do that. Can anyone please guide as to how can i debug the exact XML request that is send when a call is made.

I have tried to use below code and print the request made but i am unable to.

```
require "xmlrpc/client"    
server = XMLRPC::Client.new("www.ruby-lang.org", "/RPC2", 80)
```

- for example from the below code how can i puts or print on console
  the exact request.

Answer (score 0):

```
XMLRPC::Create.new.methodCall("sample.sumAndDifference", 5, 3)
```

---

`XMLRPC` library creates an instance of [`XMLRPC::Create`](https://github.com/ruby/xmlrpc/blob/master/lib/xmlrpc/create.rb#L104) and sends it to the server within one single method [`XMLRPC::Client#call`](https://github.com/ruby/xmlrpc/blob/master/lib/xmlrpc/client.rb#L285):

```
def call2(method, *args)
  request = create().methodCall(method, *args)
  data = do_rpc(request, false)
  parser().parseMethodResponse(data)
end
```

That said, to get the exact request XML one should mimic/emulate

```
request = create().methodCall(method, *args)
```